# Is UNIX password the root password . i changed UNIX password ? I did not find the right answer before posting this

Tags: password

To change unix password from command line:
i used :

To change the root password:

```
sudo passwd
```

This gave instructions to change the UNIX password.
It did not change my user password, who is the only user on the computer.

So which password was changed?
Im new and im lost.
Thanks

Comment: you changed the root password, root user is not you. you  have to put your user name

Comment: they best way to understand what you did is to enter the commands `whoami`  (which will respond with your username), then `sudo whoami` which should let you understand what password you changed.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the root passwd. Using the *sudo* command elevated your privileges to root and then executed the *passwd* command on itself.

To change the password of a user, run:

`sudo passwd userid`

Where *userid* is the login of the account you want to update.

You probably want to re-lock the root password as well. By default the root password is locked for security reasons. Lock the root command with:

`sudo passwd --lock root`

More information on the *passwd* command can be viewed in its manpage:

`man passwd`